# Powershell Datagridview: avoid selection of rows based on a value in cell

Tags: powershell, datagridview

I have a script that shows cells with various values. If a cell has the value '0' then it should not be possible to select the entire row.

[image: Example]

Here, the rows with the numbers 10, 11 and 13 should not be able to select.

I have the following script:

```
Function GenerateDataGrid
{
 
 For($Index = 1; $Index -le 30; $Index++)
  {

   $Record = [ordered]@{
    Follow = $Index
    Number = Random(0..5)
    }
    $Global:Table += New-Object 'PSObject' -Property $Record
  }

  $dgvTest.DataSource = [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Global:Table
  $dgvTest.SelectAll()
  $Rows = $dgvTest.SelectedRows
  ForEach ($Row in $Rows)
   {
    if($dgvTest.Rows[$Row.Index].Cells['Number'].Value -eq 0)
     {
      # $dgvTest.Rows[$Row.Index].Readonly = $True    -> Does not work
      # $dgvTest.Rows[$Row.Index].Locked = $True      -> Throws up an error
      # $dgvTest.Rows[$Row.Index].Enabled = $False    -> Throws up an error
      $dgvTest.Rows[$Row.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255, 224, 224, 224)
     }
   }
  $dgvTest.ClearSelection()
}

Function ShowResults
{
 $Rows = $dgvTest.SelectedRows
 Clear-Host
 ForEach ($Row in $Rows)
  {
   $Follow = $dgvTest.Rows[$Row.Index].Cells['Follow'].Value
   $Number = $dgvTest.Rows[$Row.Index].Cells['Number'].Value
   Write-Host "$Follow $Number"
  }     
}

$Global:Table = @()

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$frmDataGridTest = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$btnShow = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$chkAllItems = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
$btnCancel = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$dgvTest = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'

#
# frmDataGridTest
#
$frmDataGridTest.Controls.Add($btnShow)
$frmDataGridTest.Controls.Add($chkAllItems)
$frmDataGridTest.Controls.Add($btnCancel)
$frmDataGridTest.Controls.Add($dgvTest)
$frmDataGridTest.AutoScaleDimensions = New-Object System.Drawing.SizeF(6, 13)
$frmDataGridTest.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
$frmDataGridTest.CancelButton = $btnCancel
$frmDataGridTest.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(281, 464)
$frmDataGridTest.Name = 'frmDataGridTest'
$frmDataGridTest.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$frmDataGridTest.Text = 'Test DatagridView'
#
# btnShow
#
$btnShow.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(106, 385)
$btnShow.Name = 'btnShow'
$btnShow.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 50)
$btnShow.TabIndex = 3
$btnShow.Text = 'Show selected items'
$btnShow.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# chkAllItems
#
$chkAllItems.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(22, 13)
$chkAllItems.Name = 'chkAllItems'
$chkAllItems.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240, 24)
$chkAllItems.TabIndex = 2
$chkAllItems.Text = 'Select or unselect all items'
$chkAllItems.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# btnCancel
#
$btnCancel.DialogResult = 'Cancel'
$btnCancel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(187, 385)
$btnCancel.Name = 'btnCancel'
$btnCancel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 50)
$btnCancel.TabIndex = 1
$btnCancel.Text = 'Cancel'
$btnCancel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# dgvTest
#
$dgvTest.AllowUserToAddRows = $False
$dgvTest.AllowUserToDeleteRows = $False
$dgvTest.AllowUserToOrderColumns = $True
$dgvTest.AllowUserToResizeRows = $False
$dgvTest.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 'AllCells'
$dgvTest.AutoSizeRowsMode = 'AllCells'
$dgvTest.ClipboardCopyMode = 'Disable'
$dgvTest.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 'AutoSize'
$dgvTest.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(22, 43)
$dgvTest.Name = 'dgvTest'
$dgvTest.ReadOnly = $True
$dgvTest.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240, 315)
$dgvTest.TabIndex = 0

$frmDataGridTest.Add_Shown({GenerateDataGrid})
$dgvTest.SelectionMode = 'FullRowSelect'

$chkAllItems.Add_CheckedChanged({
if($chkAllItems.Checked)
 {
  $dgvTest.SelectAll()
  $Rows = $dgvTest.SelectedRows
  ForEach ($Row in $Rows)
   {
    if($dgvTest.Rows[$Row.Index].Cells['Number'].Value -eq 0)
     {
      $dgvTest.Rows[$Row.Index].Selected = $False
     }
   }
 }
  else
 {
  $dgvTest.ClearSelection()
 }      
})

$btnShow.Add_Click({ShowResults})

[void]$frmDataGridTest.ShowDialog()
[void]$frmDataGridTest.Dispose()
```

What can I do to make it possible that a user cannot select the rows with the numbers 10, 11 and 13?

Feedback is appreciated a lot.

With kind regards,
The Sting Pilot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, but you need to handle the grid's `SelectionChanged` event.

Add this event handler:

```
$dgvTest.Add_SelectionChanged({
  ForEach ($Row in $dgvTest.SelectedRows){
      $Row.Selected = ($Row.Cells['Number'].Value -ne 0)
  }
})
```

EDIT: Changing the Selected property sets the BackColor on each cell so it's no longer the default for the row. You can manually set it back to your default with this code:

```
$dgvTest.Add_SelectionChanged({
  ForEach ($Row in $dgvTest.SelectedRows){
    if($Row.Cells['Number'].Value -eq 0){
      $Row.Selected = $false
      $Row.Cells[0..1]|%{$_.Style.BackColor = [Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255, 224, 224, 224) }
    }
  }
})
```

I figured out the properties to set by putting a break point [F9] on the `$Row.Selected = $false` line and looking through the `$Row` object's properties at run time.

Comment: I am sorry to inform you but the issue has not been solved. Initially, the 'read-only' row (column 'Number' cell value = 0) have a grey background. Your solution removes that grey background.

Comment: Marked as the answer. :-) This is working fine.